# When typing a topic of a question, show some search results from google

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, google

Now when I want to post some question, I can see already asked on SO questions, listed below, when I type topic on the question form, but what if to show side by side some search results from search providers ?

On my memory, many of questions posted on SO are located on first lines on google. So why not show them too ?

Comment: That's funny.  It actually crystalizes a feeling I've had... the search results on SO as a result of typing in a question to ask, are very much better results than those from the Seach-the-site box in the upper right.  Haha... anyway...

Comment: @TomPace Just wanted to be helpful

Comment: @TomPace `With millions of garbage questions and duplicates, it is time to rethink this. –  Pëkka 4 hours ago` haha, so my question for him was like "okay, dude, you won"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, because [google](http://google.com) or [bing](http://www.bing.com/) already do that!

Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be your last resource (**always**).

You should first try to research your problem, see if you can find an answer or *something* related to your problem. We require users to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved which includes your own research and attempts trying to solve your problem.

If Stack Overflow is the first place you come to to find an answer to your question you are not following any of our rules therefore your potential question is at start exposed to downvotes and close votes (*which increases the load of moderation the community has to do*)

Comment: **-1** for linking to Bing. `</joke>`

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh: I don't know what everyones problem with bing.com is. I think it is a very neat collection of background images (and occasional background videos).

Answer (score 2):

I agree that Google often shows better results than the on-site search, but your first thought should be to Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo your problem, not go straight to SO and perhaps see a related question pop up.

Comment: The thing is, thousands of people don't do that. At least half all of my activity on SO these days consists of some form of "Have you Googled your question title?" comments

Comment: @Pëkka I think the problem in the interface of ask question form itself. maybe we should split asking process on two. to let user think about what he is doing right now. I didn't googled this too and just have not any piece of thought about i can do this at first. well maybe i'm just lazy ass, but however